# Why is my website going blank everytime I edit a row in Wp_options?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, layout, phpmyadmin

I have a wordpress theme and I am trying to change a bit of text that I can only really find in the database. It's a bit of title text that I can only find in the wp_options database.

I found the bit of text I need to change in wp_options, in a row under "of_options"

```
...";s:16:"translation_port";s:16:"Recent portfolio";s:23:"translation_relatedpost";
s:7:"Related"; s:27:"translation_advertise_title";s:28:"Our Nights";
s:20:"translation_morelink";s:9:"Read more";s:24:"port_project_description";s:20:
```

That above code does not have any breaks in it, I only changed it for ease of reading.

Just ran another test, and I dont actually have to change a single bit of text, purely opening the row for edit, then saving it without touching anything messes it up.

No logos, images, layout or anything shows. Only the background image :/

I have no idea, tried everything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never fully read it.

Was a part in the theme edit menu to change the titles under a translation tab. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to edit this field in the database.

What you see here is a serialized array.

'of_options' refers to 'Options Framework' and is an array containing all chosen options.

Look under Appearance for an options links. The values will be editable there. If somewhere else you need to add more info to your question for help to be provided.

Comment: I just need a way to edit the serialized data without it destroying my site :/

This is the outcome http://i.imgur.com/2uQn2lw.png